Columns in Revamped Visual Studio Resource Explorer
From new Visual Studio (17.11) The resource explorer got changed, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-revamped-visual-studio-resource-explorer/
The Problem is I do not see a view like displayed in that page:

But in my explorer:

The records are stacked in rows, not as a table. I did not find any option to change the view.
How to fix this?
Thanks for answer.

You should have a resource file, named Resources.resx (neutral language), and other resource files, named, e.g., Resources.de-DE.resx etc., in the same folder. Then when you add a new resource string, you should see a new row, with the new resource, and the value assigned to it in Resource Explorer. Also, one Column for each associated language resource file, with the cell content in their Columns marked in red, since the value is initially empty. You can set the value directly in Resource Explorer

This seems that you wanted to modify the table on the right side of the interface, but you actually added items to the list of the left side. Or did you have any problems while editing the table?
